# lightning-input type number has comma in between i do not want comma in this field

Tags: lightning-web-components

HTML

```
<lightning-input type="number" min="0" label="Quantity" ></lightning-input>
```

So if write something is this and out of the field then it automatically add the comma in between the number and i do not want the comma how i can remove it ?

and yeah if i am using text type instead of number type in lightning input type then comma is not coming but in text field i can write the alphabets and i want only numbers in my field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Use text type and pattern along with *message-when-pattern-mismatch*:

```
<lightning-input pattern="^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$" 
            message-when-pattern-mismatch="Only numbers can be entered"
            min="0" 
            formatter="decimal"
            label="Quantity" >
    </lightning-input>
```

**Option 2:**

Use text type and onchange handler to remove non-number values:

HTML:

```
<lightning-input 
            min="0" 
            formatter="decimal"
            onchange={handleChange}
            label="Quantity" >
    </lightning-input>
```

JS:

```
handleChange(event) {
    let inputVal = event.target.value;
    if(!isFinite(inputVal)) {
        event.target.value = inputVal.toString().slice(0,-1);
    }
}
```